# How to use spinner in multiple components

Tags: css, angular

I have multiple components.i created spinner on clicking button it's working fine but how to use spinner multiple components like drop down and radio button only one html code to be use another components in angular.I don't want to use plugins.
 Thank you

Comment: You have to create a component in which sits your spinner in order to reuse it.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what i need to do

Comment: I recommend you to follow the [official tutorials](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1#create-the-heroes-component)

Answer (score 0):

You should created a shared Spinner Component and placed inside shared folder. Using Subject you can emit an event say 'show/hide' from your source component. Listen for events in Spinner component and display/hide the spinner.

Comment: I created hide/show,but the same thing i want to use in drop down (on change )

Comment: On dropdown change method. you can emit same event and listen in the spinner component.